# javascript random from two array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to create link tag from image and link array. in this below code i can not get random from arrays. my random link tag only return first of array cells.

in each refresh i want to have another cell of array, in this code in many refresh i do not have another cell of array.

```
var img_width = "468";
var img_height = "60";
var img_title = "";
var a_title = "";
var image=new Array()

image[0]='site.com/upload/aria468.gif';
image[1]='site.com/upload/dadafarid468.gif';

var links=new Array()

links[0]='site.com';
links[1]='domain.com';

var xy=Math.floor(Math.random()*image.length);
document.write('<a title="'+a_title+'" href="'+links[xy]+'" target="_blank"><img border=0 src="'+image[xy]+'" width="'+img_width+'" height="'+img_height+'" alt="'+img_title+'"></a>');
```

Comment: It's random, so half of the time (1/n) it will be the same image as the previous time it was loaded.

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k7qFM/. Although I would recommend not using `document.write`.